# If P = NP, then 3-SAT can be solved in P

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

Prove that if $P = NP$, then there is an algorithm that can find a boolean assignment for a 3-SAT problem in P time if it exists.

$P = NP$ only says that we can decide whether a 3-SAT problem is satisfiable but it doesn't say anything about how to find a satisfying boolean expression.

Does any one know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: This question may be better at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kevin: As csteory.SE is mainly for research-level questions, this question would in all likelihood be closed quite quickly there.  This question is also **not** off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your formula and check if it is satisfiable. If so, conjoin $x_1$ to your formula, where $x_1$ is your first variable, and check if it is still satisfiable. If so, then there is an assignment where $x_1$ is true; otherwise, there is one where $x_1$ is false.

Conjoin $x_1$ or $\neg x_1$ and repeat for all of the other variables.